# Django ManyToMany model validation

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with a ManyToManyField similar to this one (the model Word has a language, too):

```
class Sentence(models.Model):
    words = models.ManyToManyField(Word)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    def clean(self):
        for word in self.words.all():
            if word.language_id != self.language_id:
                raise ValidationError('One of the words has a false language')
```

When trying to add a new sentence (e.g. through django admin) I get `'Sentence' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used`. This means I can't access self.words before saving it, but this is exactly what I'm trying to do. Is there any way to work around this so you can validate this model nevertheless? I really want to directly validate the model's fields.

I found many questions concerning this exception, but I couldn't find help for my problem. I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: If you wanted to create a Word, how would you validate that it was associated with a Sentence? It does not have a 'sentence' field in its model definition.

Comment: Not everyone uses forms. I consider this a massive flaw in Django. Does anyone have a better answer?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It is not possible to do this validation in the model's `clean` method, but you can create a model form which can validate the choice of `words`.

```
from django import forms

class SentenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sentence
        fields = ['words', 'language']

    def clean(self):
        """
        Checks that all the words belong to the sentence's language.
        """
        words = self.cleaned_data.get('words')
        language = self.cleaned_data.get('language')
        if language and words:
            # only check the words if the language is valid
            for word in words:
                if words.language != language:
                    raise ValidationError("The word %s has a different language" % word)
        return self.cleaned_data
```

You can then customise your `Sentence` model admin class, to use your form in the Django admin.

```
class SentenceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SentenceForm

admin.register(Sentence, SentenceAdmin)
```

Comment: It is regrettable to see there is no possibility to validate it directly in the model. But so far a custom ModelForm is enough for me. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Also, if your Sentence form can also be seen as an inline in another model (e.g. a Paragraph), you will want to add the line `form = SentenceForm` to the SentenceInline class as well.

Comment: @purefanatic `Model.save()` is not expected to raise `ValidationErrors` thus there's no way to validate it directly.

Comment: With django 2.2.4, I had to also add `fields = '__all__'` in the meta class, else it throws the following error - `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited`

Comment: @PushpakDagade Using `fields = '__all__'` [can lead to security issues](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use). I've added an explicit whitelist `fields = ['words', 'language']` to the example above.

Comment: Saved me from implementing pre_save() signal, Thank you.

Comment: Good Answer! Note that you must use `self.cleaned_data.get('words')` instead of `self.words` in model form.

Comment: So If I use Forms and API Serializers, I need to do the validation twice?
Once for the Form and second for API?

Answer (score 7):

According to Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) you can listen to the **m2m_changed** signal, which will trigger **pre_add** and **post_add** actions.

> Using add() with a many-to-many relationship, however, will not call any save() methods (the bulk argument doesn’t exist), but rather create the relationships using QuerySet.bulk_create(). If you need to execute some custom logic when a relationship is created, listen to the m2m_changed signal, which will trigger pre_add and post_add actions.

Comment: This certainly helps, but notice that a `ValidationError` raised in the signal handler will not be neatly shown in the admin as if it was thrown from a models or forms `clean()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it from the `clean` method on the model. It's simply not possible with the way M2M relationships work in Django. However, you can do this sort of validation on forms used to create a `Sentence` such as in the admin or a form on your site.