# How to remove current object from recursive many to many query set in Django admin site

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

If I define a Django model with a recursive relationship as follows,

```
Class M(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    ms = models.ManyToManyFied('self')
```

and in the admin site I enter data such afterwards M.a = 'a','b', and 'c'.  The Django admin site's change form will show ms to contain 'a', 'b', 'c'.  How do I remove 'a' from the list since I don't want it assigned to current M.a which is itself?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it may be a good practical solution. You can create a ModelForm that validates your data (i.e., prevents a model from setting a relationship with itself), then customize your model's admin class to use that custom form in the admin site. This SO post describes how in detail: [Django ManyToMany model validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986510/django-manytomany-model-validation)

Comment: this is a good practical solution thanks. But like you said it does not answer my question directly, still you're solution is helpful.