# Trouble overriding save method on Django model with ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm having trouble overriding the save method on a Django model to check a restriction on a many-to-many field.

Say I have the following models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ClothingItem(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person)

class Outfit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    clothing_items = models.ManyToManyField(ClothingItem)
```

I would like to put a restriction on the `save` method of `Outfit` that ensures that each `ClothingItem` in a given outfit has the same owner as the `Outfit` itself.

I.e. I'd like to write:

```
class Outfit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    clothing_items = models.ManyToManyField(ClothingItem)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for ci in self.clothing_items:
            if ci.owner != self.owner:
                raise ValueError('You can only put your own items in an outfit!)
        super(Outfit, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but when I try that I get an error about `<Outfit: SundayBest>" needs to have a value for field "outfit" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues going on here. To directly answer your question, the error basically means: You cannot refer to any m2m relationship if the original object(an instance of `Outfit` here) is not saved in database.

Sounds like you are trying to do the validation in `save()` method, which is a pretty bad practice in django. The verification process should typically happen in `Form` that creates `Outfit` objects. To override default django form, please refer to [django ModelAdmin.form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form). To understand how to do validation on django forms, check [ModelForm validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform).

If you want code to refer to for m2m validation, I found a [good example from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986510/django-manytomany-model-validation?answertab=votes#7986937).