# Django: Check at model level if anything in ManyToMany field before saving

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, many-to-many, django-orm

There's a lot of questions worded similarly, but every single one I've seen is somebody trying to get some kind of data through a ManyToMany relationship before saving it. I'm not trying to *use* the relationship at all before saving, I just want to see if the user put *anything* there or not.

My model has a ForeignKey field pointing to a parent model, and two ManyToMany fields pointing to other models, but I only want users to be able to use one M2M field or the other, not both. This model is being edited through the admin as an inline on its parent.

**models.py**

```
class ProductSpecial(models.Model):
    # name, slug, image, etc

class ProductSpecialAmount(models.Model):
    special = models.ForeignKey(ProductSpecial, related_name='amounts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    brands = models.ManyToManyField(ProductBrand, related_name='specials', blank=True)
    lines = models.ManyToManyField(ProductLine, related_name='specials', blank=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
class ProductSpecialAmountInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ProductSpecialAmount
    # fieldsets, etc

@admin.register(ProductSpecial)
class ProductSpecialAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProductSpecialAmountInline]
    # fieldsets, etc
```

I only want users to be able to choose from brands or lines, but not both, and I would like to validate this before save and throw a validation error if necessary. My initial attempt was to just do...

```
class ProductSpecialAmount(models.Model):
    # ...
    def clean(self):
        if self.brands and self.lines:
            raise ValidationError('Please choose either brands or lines, not both', code='invalid')
```

...but that throws `ValueError: "<ProductSpecialAmount: ProductSpecialAmount object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

I get that I can't actually query the related ProductBrand or ProductModel objects before this object is saved, but I don't actually want any data from those objects right now, I just want to know if the user left either of the fields blank or not, and am wondering if that's possible to see at the model level.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you actually want to use the data from a field or just see if it is blank, the problem is caused by referencing the m2m field in any way before saving the object. I had a similar problem which I fixed using a custom form as per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7986937/19837155

This might be more difficult when you're using inlines, but it may be the easiest way to solve your problem.